# Syntaxhighlighter is not working on blogger

Tags: blogger, syntaxhighlighter

Hi I've used following links:

http://www.cyberack.com/2007/07/adding-syntax-highlighter-to-blogger.html

I followed step by step but I couldn't get it working on my blog. It prints as its whatever is written there as if it ignoring the tag itself.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Since it seems to be very simple task but I found it very strange why it's not working for me.

Here is the link for my test blog:
http://nishantcop.blogspot.sg/2012/07/blog-post_27.html

Comment: Guys any one has any update on this..

Thanks in advance for your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are pasting your HTML code into Compose part. CHange your post view to HTML view and then change it. It should work now then!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed that was the issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

That is right. Just switch to HTML tab from Compose tab. That button is located at up-right side of blogger.

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial on a slightly more optimized blogger configuration for the Syntaxhighlighter setup.
http://modelarchitecture.blogspot.com/2013/12/configuring-javascript-syntaxhighligher.html

Answer (score 0):

HTTP protocol is not working with blogger.I tried .js and .css files hosting on google dive. It is working for me.

Bloger theme HTML screenshot
[image]

Also you can read my blog for more details click on [Syntaxhighlighter in blogger](https://my-tech-expert.blogspot.com/2018/08/how-to-use-syntaxhighlighter-in-blogger.html)